# How can I select 2 specific edges all around this gear?

Tags: modeling, select

[image: gear]
How can I quickly select those two edges all the way around the circle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Checker Deselect for this.

1. Select all the edges around using *Select > Edge Rings*
2. Deselect one of the edges (Shift + LMB) to break the loop
3. Use *Select > Checker Deselect* (play with the values, and adjust offset if needed)
4. Add that one edge to selection (again using Shift + LMB)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First suggestion: work under an Array modifier, based on a rotated Empty at the wheel's center. That way, all adjustments you make to one cog will be reflected in all the others.

But you could make a reasonably quick selection:

- Select one of the edges of interest
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > select similar > direction
- In an orthographic view, using circle-select, enclose the unwanted (inner) edges in that direction, and middle-click, deselect those.